# JavaScripts not working in mac OS, iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, macos, safari, mobile-safari

I wrote js code for wordpress website, and unfortunetly it is not working in safari and every browser in mac system. I don't know why. My scripts should react for 'click' event and charge input value. In windows evrything is ok, but in safari, mac, iphone not. 
I'm not sure where is a error, in safari console i can't see any mistake. My code is a little long, so if you want help me, i can send you link for my website.

```
<button id="checkBank" class="checkNumberButton" type="submit"><span>Sprawdź</span></button> 

document.querySelector("#checkBank").addEventListener("click", function () {my code here}
```

Where i can find information about difference between apple system and windows?

Comment: Try `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`.. My guess is submit action is taking over event listener..

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close `addEventListener`. This should work (works on my Mac)

```
document.querySelector("#checkBank").addEventListener("click", function () {alert("test")});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpeyr870/

Comment: yes i make mistake only here, but in code is ok, because it working in windows  and android. Meybe i send you link to my app?

Comment: Sure, put it in your post ;)

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me. I inspected your code and Safari does what it has to. When I click the button the textbox gets a red border.

Comment: ok, could you give me screen, because i don't have safari browser ?:c you should have red border and new div with information below